# how to make this code run only before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert my users' ips from string to integers :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  [:current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip].each do |field|
    define_method(field) do
      ip = read_attribute(field)
      return nil unless ip
      ip += 4_294_967_296 if ip < 0 # Convert from 2's complement
      "#{(ip & 0xFF000000) >> 24}.#{(ip & 0x00FF0000) >> 16}.#{(ip & 0x0000FF00) >> 8}.#{ip & 0x000000FF}"
    end

    define_method("#{field}=") do |value|
      quads = value.split('.')
      if quads.length == 4
        as_int = (quads[0].to_i * (2**24)) + (quads[1].to_i * (2**16)) + (quads[2].to_i * (2**8)) + quads[3].to_i
        as_int -= 4_294_967_296 if as_int > 2147483647 # Convert to 2's complement
      else
        as_int = nil
      end
      write_attribute(field, as_int)
    end

  end
end
```

This code works fine, it converts the string to integers and saves them. However, I want this code to run only before_create action. I tried to put it in a `before_create do` block but I got errors about `undefined method define_method' for #<User:0x007fb97c7076b8>` . Even if you could just direct me to the right direction that'd be great.

Thanks

Comment: What is your end goal here? Something smells.

Comment: @DickieBoy I inherited this code and I believe it smells too. But there is a functionality that I am trying to implement and kinda hard to explain in comments.

Comment: Been there, done that. No more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute it against the eigenclass of the object:

```
before_create do
  class << self
    [:current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip].each do |field|
      define_method(field) do
        ip = read_attribute(field)
        return nil unless ip
        ip += 4_294_967_296 if ip < 0 # Convert from 2's complement
        "#{(ip & 0xFF000000) >> 24}.#{(ip & 0x00FF0000) >> 16}.#{(ip & 0x0000FF00) >> 8}.#{ip & 0x000000FF}"
      end

      define_method("#{field}=") do |value|
        quads = value.split('.')
        if quads.length == 4
          as_int = (quads[0].to_i * (2**24)) + (quads[1].to_i * (2**16)) + (quads[2].to_i * (2**8)) + quads[3].to_i
          as_int -= 4_294_967_296 if as_int > 2147483647 # Convert to 2's complement
        else
          as_int = nil
        end
        write_attribute(field, as_int)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Worked like charm! I can't thank you enough. I have been trying this for 5 hours now. Thanks very much, Accepting soon.